# Mysql: Query Needed

Tags: mysql

Suppose we have a mysql table:

```
id number date
1  3      2016-01-01
2  1      2016-01-03
3  4      2016-01-04
4  1      2016-01-04
...
...
...
```

How we can retrieve the **date** that sum of number column starting from **2016-01-01** reaches **6**?

Something like:

```
SELECT date FROM table WHERE date >= '2016-01-01' 
HAVING SUM(number) > 6
```

For example current result should be '2016-01-04'. At this date sum of number column exceeds 6.

Comment: Please add more details explaining what you are trying to get? This is very unclear.

Comment: That you want to accomplish something like this screams terrible database design.

Comment: Of course, but some times there is no more table in database and you should get the results from the same table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below:

```
SET @i=0;
SELECT MIN(`date`) As `Date`
FROM Table1 
WHERE `date` >= '2016-01-01' AND (@i := @i + `number`) > 6
ORDER BY `date`
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/86319/9)

More about using in-line variables: [Advanced MySQL user variable techniques](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/15/advanced-mysql-user-variable-techniques/)

Comment: Awesome, Can you please add some explanation about this in-line variable in this particular example?

Comment: Have you read the article I linked to?